# points way off from ESRI source

Tags: python, arcgis, shapefile, esri

I [downloaded](https://www.stlouis-mo.gov/data/upload/data-files/prcl_shape.zip) the City of St. Louis parcel data, and I get points information that looks like `(564433.152, 1037664.554)`.  I thought this might just need to be divided by 10,000 or something to get degrees, but it's clearly not a direct mapping.  I did a bit of research and thought these might be UTM coordinates or something, but that doesn't pan out either.  For reference, St. Louis is about 38.5N by 90.5W.  Any ideas?  Code:

```
import shapefile
sf = shapefile.Reader("prcl")
for i in sf.iterShapeRecords():
     parcel = i.record[0]
     points = i.shape.points
     p2 = list(map(lambda x: [y/10000 for y in x], i.shape.points))
     print(parcel,points,p2)
```

Comment: This is not a question about programming. It is a question about City of St. Louis parcel data. I don't think stackoverflow is the right place for such a question.

Comment: or it could be an issue with the way I'm using the library.  I am using it in the most plain-vanilla way I can think of, so I'm wondering if there might just be a few toggles to flip.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer here is much more interesting and deep than either the proposal that there was something wrong with the data, or my idea that I was using the library incorrectly.  I forgot that I had a working KML produced using `ogr2ogr` from GDAL.  I thought, okay- clearly GDAL knows how to convert these coordinates- but how is it doing it.  I thought it might be a bit easier to look at a JSON file, so I ran `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON prcl.json prcl.dbf`.  This produced, as expected, a JSON file- but it had a really interesting entry in the first few lines:

```
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::26796" } }
```

It turns out this is a special coordinate system that applies just for a small section of the US, and you can [read more about it here](https://epsg.io/26796).  Sadly, I don't yet have a good programmatic way of converting systems, but it is interesting to know where those numbers came from.